# SSRS 2008 Export to Excel on iPad

Tags: excel, ipad, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS 2008 instance, integrated on my SharePoint 2010 site.  We have a number of reports served up, and especially now that Microsoft has Excel for iPad, we're looking to give iPads to our salesfolk because it will make them <strike>look cooler and increase sales 50%</strike> more productive.

On an iPad, I get the Export option, but it only has the option to export as TIFF and PDF, nothing else.. unlike on a PC where I have the option to do Excel, CSV, XML, and other stuff.

Has anyone found a workaround for this issue?  Is there any way I can "always show" Excel as an export option?  If not, does anyone know if upgrading to SSRS 2012 will alleviate this issue?  We need to upgrade at some point.. just don't want to tackle that headache until I have to..

Comment: Same issue on SSRS 2012.

Comment: I've decompiled ReportViewer library (version 11.0.3366.16 downloaded from Nuget) and found an internal method which checks if the browser is iOS and then iterates over available rendering extensions, checks if black list contains each item and returns only those that don't exist in black list. So I guess there is no way we can override this behaviour, since its internal class plus the black list is instantiated in private static contructor of ReportViewer class. There's a possibility to programmatically export your report in desired format, check this SO [link](http://tinyurl.com/qjmv74p)